# How to delete the last row and add more rows in the tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

there is a button in the last row of the tableview, when press it, I want the button in that row disappear, at the same time, add more rows, then, the button appear in the last row again.
but I do not know how to make it!
here is my code:

```
- (void)morePicture:(id)sender{
NSMutableArray *indexpath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[photos removeObjectAtIndex:[photos count]-1];
[indexpath addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[photos count]+1 inSection:0]];
[table beginUpdates];
[table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexpath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

NSMutableArray *indexPathss = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    [photos addObject:s];
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [indexPathss addObject:indexpath];
}
```

Comment: Does this code work at all for you? If `photos` is your data source, then it seems that you're attempting to delete rows at an indexPath row that is greater than the number of items in your source (`[photos count]+1` should be `[photos count]`).

Comment: If the button will always be the last thing in the table, it might be easier to just put it in the footer view for the table. That way it will always be at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIButton *moreButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[moreButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_signin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMoreRows) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Add button to table footer view

self.tableView.tableFooterView = moreButton;

And in method

-(IBAction) showMoreRows {

// Add object in array which is responsible for creating table view and then called

[self.tableView reloadData];

}

Comment: by the way, how can i set the height of the footer view?

Comment: You can set Frame of button j

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method. Use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` instead. Just add rows above last row button, don't delete it!

```
NSArray *newPhotos = ....;
NSMutableArray *photos = ...;

// insert new photos first (before table update)
[photos insertObjects:newPhotos atIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange([photos count] - 1, [newPhotos count])];

NSMutableArray *newIndices = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger row = [photos count] - [newPhotos count] - 1; row < [photos count] - 1; row++) {
    [newIndices addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:row];
}
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newIndices withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: however, after i pressed the button, it add more rows, but the button do not show again